# Apache pyspark using oracle jdbc to pull data. Driver cannot be found

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using apache spark pyspark (spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6) on windows 7.

I keep getting this error when I run my python script in pyspark.

An error occured while calling o23.load. java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:------------------------------------connection

Here is my python file

```
import os

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "C:\\spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6"
os.environ["SPARK_CLASSPATH"] = "L:\\Pyspark_Snow\\ojdbc6.jar"

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark_config = SparkConf().setMaster("local[8]")  
sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_config) 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = (sqlContext
    .load(source="jdbc",
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin://x.x.x.x/xdb?user=xxxxx&password=xxxx",
          dbtable="x.users")
 )
sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately changing environment variable `SPARK_CLASSPATH` won't work. You need to declare

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath L:\\Pyspark_Snow\\ojdbc6.jar
```

in your `/path/to/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` or simply execute `spark-submit` job with additional argument `--jars`:

```
spark-submit --jars "L:\\Pyspark_Snow\\ojdbc6.jar" yourscript.py
```

Comment: Cool, glad to help you out!

Comment: spark-defaults.conf worked perfectly for me (after all of the other ways failed). thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To set the jars programatically set the following config:
`spark.yarn.dist.jars` with comma-separated list of jars.

Eg:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Spark config example") \
        .config("spark.yarn.dist.jars", "<path-to-jar/test1.jar>,<path-to-jar/test2.jar>") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

Or as below:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark_config = SparkConf().setMaster("local[8]")
spark_config.set("spark.yarn.dist.jars", "L:\\Pyspark_Snow\\ojdbc6.jar")
sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_config) 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

Or pass `--jars` with the path of `jar` files separated by `,` to `spark-submit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the jar using --jars and --driver-class-path and then set the driver specifically. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36328672/1547734