# Working with jdbc jar in pyspark

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to read from a postgres sql database in pyspark.
I know this has been asked before such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669420/not-able-to-connect-to-postgres-using-jdbc-in-pyspark-shell), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821518/apache-spark-jdbc-connection-not-working) and many other places, however, the solutions there either use a jar in the local running directory or copy it to all workers manually.

I downloaded the postgresql-9.4.1208 jar and placed it in /tmp/jars. I then proceeded to call pyspark with the --jars and --driver-class-path switches:

```
pyspark --master yarn --jars /tmp/jars/postgresql-9.4.1208.jar --driver-class-path /tmp/jars/postgresql-9.4.1208.jar
```

Inside pyspark I did:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:postgresql://ip_address:port/db_name?user=myuser&password=mypasswd", dbtable="table_name").load()
df.count()
```

However, while using --jars and --driver-class-path worked fine for jars I created, it failed for jdbc and I got an exception from the workers:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did not find registered driver with class org.postgresql.Driver
```

If I copy the jar manually to all workers and add --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath and  --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath, it does work (with the same jar). The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) btw suggests using SPARK_CLASSPATH which is deprecated actually adds these two switches (but has the side effect of preventing adding OTHER jars with the --jars option which I need to do)

So my question is: what is special about the jdbc driver which makes it not work and how can I add it without having to manually copy it to all workers.

**Update:**

I did some more looking and found this in the documentation:
"The JDBC driver class must be visible to the primordial class loader on the client session and on all executors. This is because Java’s DriverManager class does a security check that results in it ignoring all drivers not visible to the primordial class loader when one goes to open a connection. One convenient way to do this is to modify compute_classpath.sh on all worker nodes to include your driver JARs.".

The problem is I can't seem to find computer_classpath.sh nor do I understand what the primordial class loader means.

I did find [this](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201504.mbox/%3CCAAOnQ7vHeBwDU2_EYeMuQLyVZ77+N_jDGuinxOB=sfF2LKCDow@mail.gmail.com%3E) which basically explains that this needs to be done locally.
I also found [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/5782) which basically says there is a fix but it is not yet available in version 1.6.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution which works (Don't know if it is the best one so feel free to continue commenting).
Apparently, If I add the option: driver="org.postgresql.Driver", this works properly. i.e. My full line (inside pyspark) is:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:postgresql://ip_address:port/db_name?user=myuser&password=mypasswd", dbtable="table_name",driver="org.postgresql.Driver").load()
df.count()
```

Another thing: If you are already using a fat jar of your own (I am in my full application) then all you need to do is add the jdbc driver to your pom file as such:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.1208</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then you don't have to add the driver as a separate jar, just use the jar with dependencies.

Comment: That's exactly the "official" workaround for that regression, which appears to be specific to Spark 1.6.1, as described in **SPARK-14204** c/o Kevin McHale https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14204

Comment: I really wish I understood how this works, as I'm not able to get java code that's not a JDBC driver to load.  In fact, if I try to get the driver class from py4j, it tells me that the class is not found.  Do JDBC drivers use a different py4j gateway?

Answer (score 0):

What version of the documentation are you looking at ?
It seems like `compute-classpath.sh` was deprecated a while back - as of Spark 1.3.1:

```
$ unzip -l spark-1.3.1.zip | egrep '\.sh' | egrep classpa
 6592  2015-04-11 00:04   spark-1.3.1/bin/compute-classpath.sh

$ unzip -l spark-1.4.0.zip | egrep '\.sh' | egrep classpa
```

produces nothing.

I think you should be using load-spark-env.sh to set your classpath:

```
$/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/load-spark-env.sh
```

and you'll need to set SPARK_CLASSPATH in your `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` file (which you'll copy over from the template file `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh.template`).

Comment: as you can see from my link (repeated here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) I looked at the latest documentation (see the troubleshooting section). The whole section has deprecated element (as I said, it still has SPARK_CLASSPATH which is also deprecated)

Comment: You're right. I am able to get back results successfully - albeit running yarn on localhost:
```>>> df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myprojects?user=XXX&password=XXX", dbtable="django_session").load()
>>> df.count
<bound method DataFrame.count of DataFrame[session_key: string, session_data: string, expire_date: timestamp]>```
```>>> df.count()
4```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is another manifestation of the issue described and fixed here: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/12000.  I authored that fix 3 weeks ago and there has been no movement on it.  Maybe if others also express the fact that they have been affected by it, it may help?

Comment: I wonder why anyone did a -1 since **you correctly report that it is a Spark regression**